# Preventing fraudulent credit card authorization attempts - carding

Tags: security, pci, credit-card, fraud

What are some solutions for preventing fraudulent credit card authorization attempts?

Magento captcha no longer seems to do anything and attempts with several reCaptcha modules has not worked either.

Most fraud prevention tools seem to alert of potential fraud, but not prevent repeated bot attempts.

Comment: We've been looking for a carding solution as well, but one just doesn't seem to exist.  Most likely we'll have to write for our customer.

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/plugincompany-fraudprevention.html ?